# How to display Command window when executed from ASP.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

My application was built on .NET Windows Forms

I have to convert the application to work as web application now.

Many fuctions have worked with no change what so ever

I used to have a function that executes command and opens command prompt window.

I put the code in ASP.net web application, the code is fine and commands get executed but the problem is that command prompt window does not show any more.

The code has not changed.

I wonder how can I get command prompt window appear in the server-side so admin can know if there is command error or any other issues?

This is the function that I use to execute a command

```
   static void ExecuteCommand(string command, string workingFolder)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;
        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: you are aware, that your command is executed on server, right?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes and I mentioned in my question that I want the command window to be displayed in the server-side.

Comment: besides the fact that this is a terrible idea, you just can't show a window from IIS-hosted web application. You may try your luck with [Process.StandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netcore-3.1) however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1) you can keep open the command window with `"/K" flag`

> If the fileName parameter represents a command (.cmd) file, the
> arguments parameter must include either a "/c" or "/k" argument to
> specify whether the command window exits or remains after completion.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + command);            
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder; 
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);         
process.WaitForExit();
```

But in order to get the error and show it to your admin you have to use [`StandardError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netcore-3.1) and you can see the examples in the documentation.